# OpenCV unable to import into Spyder

Tags: python, opencv

I've followed this tutorial exactly (up to the copy and paste part):
http://mathalope.co.uk/2015/05/07/opencv-python-how-to-install-opencv-python-package-to-anaconda-windows/

For whatever reason, even after copying the cv2.pyd file and pasting it into the Anaconda3 site-packages folder, I still am unable to get import cv to work.
When I call import cv, I keep getting this error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Mia/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mia/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-8ac32963ba13>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Mia/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mia/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Mia/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It doesn't seem to recognize cv2.pyd even though it is in the Anaconda3 folder, is this due to an update or am I going about this the wrong way? I am not the admin of this computer and I believe Anaconda, python, and openCV were installed for all users, though I am not sure this makes a difference.

To be clear, there is not a folder labeled Anaconda, just Anaconda3. I figured this would  not make a difference, but now I am not too sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of moving cv2.pyd no longer works with the recent version of Anaconda. Instead I did a reinstall and typed this into the Anaconda terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Make sure your PATH is correct and that your *computer* terminal recognizes conda.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda propmt with admin access and run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I had typed my opencv program in spyder and ran it, I got "No module named 'cv2.cv2'" error. I uninstalled / reinstalled several times and tried all solutions available on the internet.

Then I ran the program outside of spyder i.e. python  and it worked. For some reason, sypder gives the error. Check if this occurs at your end.